# get column values from jquery grid on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have created a dynamic table using jquery. And binded the rows and columns dynamically from database. Appended to each row a checkbox as well."dynamictable" is a div tag created and table is appended to it. Below is the code snippet.

```
$('#dynamictable').append(
  '<table class="table custom-table table-bordered table-hover"></table>'
);
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
----
rowHeader += "<th>" + colName[i] + "</th>";
--
table.append(rowHeader);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.rows.length; i++)
{
    row = '';
    if (jsonData.rows.length > 0) {
        row += "<tbody><tr class='row_odd'>";
        row += "<td class='model_bt' onclick='show_hide(" + i + ")'>" +
               '<input type="checkbox" id=ch'+i+' onclick="displayChart()"/>' +
               jsonData.rows[i].cell[2] + "</td>";

        row += "<td>" + jsonData.rows[i].cell[3] + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + jsonData.rows[i].cell[4] + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + jsonData.rows[i].cell[5] + "</td>";
        row += "</tr></tbody>";
   }
   table.append(row);
}
```

Now onclick of the checkbox i need to get one of the entire column value. How can i acheive it. Below is my grid sample result,

```
colum1    colum2   colum3
 aa         1        10
 bb         2        20
 --         --       --
```

Need to get column2 value in an array as,
var colvals=[];

Any suggessions,

Regards

Comment: if i check 'aa' you want 1,2 in an array right

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @sangeetha : you were saying , `you have appended a checkbox to each row, and now you are saying you want to get entire column value on change event of checkbox`. these two are conflicting with each others.

Comment: I just want to find entire column value.

Comment: @Sangeetha: See this. do you want to like this 
http://jsfiddle.net/vphb0rfm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on click to checkbox , store the value in an array . 
Your Js :

```
$('*[id^=ch]').on('change',function(){
    var ar=[];
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not('td:eq(0)').each(function(i){
        ar.push($(this).html())
        });
    }else{
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vphb0rfm/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below code.

```
function displayChart(pos) {
    var items = [];
    $('#tableId tbody tr td:nth-child('+pos+')').each( function(){
       //add item to array
       items.push( $(this).text() );       
    });
    alert(items);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if pos is position yo mean?

Comment: @sangeetha yes, you need to pass the position.